# Output file for users

Tags: php, html, mysql

Okay explaining the site im building might be kind-of hard but basically the user is suppose to upload some basic data about them selfs such as first and last name age city state and a photo of them selfs

I have all this data going to a mysql server and have made that safe with pdo thanks to some user here on stack overflow but now that I have finished taking all the data I was curious about making this data visible.

My instinct was to have the php file make a output file on my directory

So basic example I sign up with 
FirstName:Jeff
LastName:Fisher
UniqueRandomIDGen:50af3da6bd0da

Would take that data and upload it mysql then create file in directory with the fallowing data
MYDOMAIN.Com/ACCOUNTS/Jeff_Fisher_50af3da6bd0da

```
file_put_contents('FirstName_LastName_UniqueRanodmIDGEN.html', 'ENTER HTML');
```

And the code in that file would basicly just create a mysqli php script that would pull the data for only Jeff Fisher with the random code 50af3da6bd0da

Now This is just my instinct from c++ and other scripting languages let me know if this is way over elaborate and pointless and how you would go about this.

Comment: Why do you want to create a static html file with PHP? You can easily mix php and html to generate the page dynamically for each user.

Comment: im personally fine with that of course but how can I make it where the users url will be 

http://www.mydomain.com/jeff_fisher_randomjunk

That is my thing I want each user to have a url that is specific to them and is there first and last name so that is why I did it but im new so let me know if there is a way to do that lol

Comment: in that case you have to look at URL Rewriting (if you are using apache see [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/)).

Comment: thanks ill start looking at it and see if I can make it work